# How to display base_footprint outline in rviz?

Tags: ros, rviz, base-footprint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've defined a base_footprint tf frame: map --> odom --> base_footprint --> base_link -->> camera frames

A footprint is defined in costmap_common_params.yaml

My .urdf.xacro file is read and parsed correctly during rviz initialization.
(Is this where a base_footprint outline should be defined?)

How do I display the base_footprint outline in rviz?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62578/how-to-display-base_footprint-outline-in-rviz?/) by [r356c](https://answers.ros.org/users/4868/r356c/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Robot footprint
It shows the footprint of the robot; in our case, the robot has a footprint, which
has a width of 0.4 meters and a height of 0.4 meters. Remember that this parameter
is configured in the  costmap_common_params file. This dimension is important
because the navigation stack will move the robot in a safe mode using the values
configured before.
•  Topic: local_costmap/robot_footprint
•  Type: geometry_msgs/Polygon
image:[image]

---

Originally posted by [redskydeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22936/redskydeng/) with karma: 118 on 2015-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0